# .htaccess question in association with codeigniter setup

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I am fairly noobish at .htaccess rewriting.

Currently this is my setup for my codeigniter setups:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This works fine when I am rewriting EVERYTHING to the index.php.  The problem is, I am trying to install a forum to www.site.com/forums/ and of course this doesnt work because it rewrites it to the main index.php.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the CodeIgniter .htaccess that I use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Generally speaking, the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

rules should prevent existing files or directories from being rewritten to index.php, but you can also duplicate the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public.*
```

rule to be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^forums.*
```

and it should accomplish the same goal, in your case.